# How to start a session with one site before accessing another?

Tags: php

I want to pull XML data from one website. However, I have to first establish a connection to another before being authorized to read such data.

I understand this question is very vague, and I'll try to answer any question I can.

I have to pull XML data from a site (lets call it site2). However, in order to view this data, I have to first visit site1 that has a user id in the link. I'm not sure at all how this works, but it works when I simply visit site1 first, then visit site2 in a browser. However, I don't know how to implement this in PHP, possibly due to my lack of understanding of what's going on.

I included some commented out lines because those are things i've tried, but ended up in nothing being printed to the screen. As is, I pull the very little data I can access without first visiting site1.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
#header('Content-Type: text/html');
#header("Location: site1");

$url = "site1.php?user_id=guest1";
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$url = "site2.php";
$response = file_get_contents($url);


print ($response);
$data = simplexml_load_string($response);
//print_r($data);
echo '<br>';
```

Expected result: About 100 lines of XML data

Actual result: Only one.

Comment: There is someting site1 is doing that is providing some sort of access token to site 2.  Cookie, http referrer (poor security but it works like a locked screen door), maybe a different header if it isn't a straight <a href="..."> type link.

Comment: I think you're trying to session hijack which isn't possible. If site 2 expects a cookie, from site 1 then it is done through site 1. You'd need to build a proxy to site 1 before then accessing site 2. If site 1 has an API which gives you a resource token to use on site 2, this is fine. Otherwise, you're looking to scrape site 2, not session hijack it which would mean creating proxies and a long process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is a vague question, however, if site2 is looking for a cookie from site1 (perhaps, subdomain?) then using PHP curl's `cookiejar` may help.

Change your requests from `file_get_contents($url)` to using a curl request.

In the curl requests, ensure you link to an empty `.txt` file on the server (this is so it will store your cookies).

When you send a request to site2, it sends the cookies you received from site1.

**An example:**

```
$cookiejar = 'cookiejar.txt';
// Delete the old cookies from the last request:
if (file_exists($cookiejar)) unlink($cookiejar);

$ch = curl_init();

// Set our curl options:
$url = "site1.php?user_id=guest1";
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $cookiejar, // Cookies saved
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $cookiejar, // Cookies saved
));

// Execute curl and return results:
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE */

// Your new url:
$url = "site2.php";
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $cookiejar, // Cookies loaded
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $cookiejar, // Cookies loaded
));

// Execute curl and return results:
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Close curl:
curl_close($ch);
```

You can obviously customise these curl requests to be what they need to be.

Comment: This code looks a lot cleaner than what I currently have too. Thank you! +1

Comment: Glad it was helpful.

Comment: I have one more question. When I get this xml data and try to just parse through it with simpleXML, I'm getting errors. When I look at the raw output, the XML header is commented out. I tried prepending a proper XML header, but it just keeps getting automatically commented out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.

Using HTTPHeaderLive, I saw site1 was storing a cookie. The cookie was the same every time I reloaded the page, so I hard-coded it into my PHP script as a header and sent it with my file_get_contents() call, and it worked!

The cookie expires on session, So I'll find a way to do this automatically in my script. But we're good for now.

Comment: I'm just about to post an answer which you may find useful.